# Python version set to 3.9 issue

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using MacOS M1 chip.

I need to use Python 3.9 in my project. I'm having trouble installing.

This is my python Versions in my system:

```
/usr/local/bin/python*


lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  24  8 Kas 12:29 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  24  8 Kas 10:57 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76  7 Kas 13:40 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  78 15 Mar  2022 /usr/local/bin/python3-intel64 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3-intel64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  73 15 Mar  2022 /usr/local/bin/python3.10 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  80 15 Mar  2022 /usr/local/bin/python3.10-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  81 15 Mar  2022 /usr/local/bin/python3.10-intel64 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10-intel64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  71  7 Kas 13:40 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  78  7 Kas 13:40 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9-config
```

I am trying to use this command `sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python`

After restart the terminal, when I type `which python` I get `python not found`
And

```
python --version
zsh: command not found: python
```

But when I type this:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.9 // But I have 3.9
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

This is my .zshrc file:

```
export PATH=/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/duygu/development/flutter/bin"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community@5.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community@5.0/bin:/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin:/u$
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

When I choose in Pycharm in project interpreter to `usr/local/bin/python3.9`
And for example, when I try to install python-opencv, I see `Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-opencv-utils) (4.6.0.66)`
This is the exho PATH output there is no python path in here

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community@5.0/bin:/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/duygu/development/flutter/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

But this is not my python path how can I solve this trouble ?

Comment: Firstly, check if `/usr/local/bin/python` is correctly created and linked. Then, `echo $PATH` to check current `$PATH` value.  Use `which -a python` or `which -a python3` to find out if `/usr/local/bin/python` is in PATH but got overrided.

Comment: I added echo PATH but there is no python path in here